# Android: get coordinates of a row in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, showcaseview

I want to use a [Showcase library](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) in order to show a message in an item of a row of a `RecyclerView`.

In order to do this, I  need to pass to the library the coordinates of the item, and I do this in the adapter. The problem is that in the `onBindViewHolder` method, the coordinates are still 0.
How could I properly get the coordinates?

The way I'm doing it is the following:

```
if (position == 2) {
            final int x = (int) ((RecyclerViewPlaceViewHolder) holder).mPlaceDescriptionTextView
                    .getX();
            final int y = (int) ((RecyclerViewPlaceViewHolder) holder).mPlaceDescriptionTextView
                    .getY();
            new ShowcaseView.Builder((Activity) mContext)
                    .setTarget(new Target() {
                        @Override
                        public Point getPoint() {
                            return new Point(x, y);
                        }
                    })
                    .setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
                    .setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button")
                    .hideOnTouchOutside()
                    .build();
        }
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you find a reliable solution?

Comment: try this:                                                                                                                      int[] originalPos = new int[2];
holder.ivAnimateView.getLocationOnScreen(originalPos);                Log.d("viewPosition","x=" + originalPos[0] + "y=" + originalPos[1]);